# ElasticSearch Sorted Index not working as expected with multiple shards

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search, indexing

I have an elastic index with default sort mapping of price:

```
shop_prices_sort_index

    "sort" : {
      "field" : "enrich.price",
      "order" : "desc"
    },
```

If I insert 10 documents:

```
100, 98, 10230, 34, 1, 23, 777, 2323, 3, 109
```

And Fetch results using /_search. By default it returns documents in order of price descending.

```
10230, 2323...
```

But if I distribute my documents into 3 shards, Then the same query returns some other sequence of products:

```
100, 98, 34...
```

I am really stuck here, I am not sure if I am missing out something basic or Do I need any extra settings to make a Sorted Index behave correctly.

PS: I also tried 'routing' & 'preference'. but no luck.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: PS: I also tried different search types: 
 "Query Then Fetch" and "DFS Query Then Fetch". None of 'em is returning the expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When configuring [index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html), you're only making sure that **each segment inside each shard** is properly sorted. The goal of index sorting is to provide some [more optimization during searches](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-sorting-elasticsearch-6-0)

Due to the distributed nature of ES, when your index has many shards, each shard will be properly sorted, but your search query **will still need to use sorting** explicitly.

So if your index settings contains the following to apply sorting at indexing time

```
"sort" : {
  "field" : "enrich.price",
  "order" : "desc"
}
```

your search queries will also need to contain the same sort specification at query time

```
"sort" : {
  "field" : "enrich.price",
  "order" : "desc"
}
```

By using index sorting you'll hit a little overhead at indexing time, but your search queries will be a bit faster in the end.

Comment: If I have to specify sort in every search query, then there is no point of using a sorted index :) 
The reason I want to use a sorted index is so that, my search queries return a sorted result without any filters.

To make more sense here - I want to use this sorted index with function_score.
So while I use function_score to rank documents, I want the default order to be based on this sorted index. This is creating an issue 'coz of the shards I believe.

Comment: First, I think you haven't read the blog article I linked to and which explains what index sorting is all about. I think you're missing the point of index sorting, whose main goal is to make it faster to search for data at search time and not have to scan the entire segments. Second, if you're using function_score it means you want to influence the score, and hence the default index sorting is useless in that case since it will never kick in. You can always get away with an index with a single shard (if you have < 20/50GB of data) and in that case, index sorting will work the way you expect.

Comment: Yes, I do understand the use of index sorting. 
But I am trying to create something different which looks like a big hack now.
- Use function_score with score_mode as 'first' and boost_mode as 'replace'. This is a requirement of the feature I am building. And before even I use function_score, I want the default order to be sorted. For eg, I can give a score of 100 to products with a category 10, But at the same time, sort these matching products with price.
I wish I could explain with more detailed example. But anyways, as a workaround I used a single shard and so far it seems to work.