# Are updated data in an elastic sorted index still ordered?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets assume I have a **sorted** index (elasticsearch) like this

GuyA;150 -
GuyB;101 -
GuyC;74 -
GuyD;12

If I insert a new entry lets say GuyE;90 the index should be organized as such :

GuyA;150 -
GuyB;101 -
GuyE;90 -
GuyC;74 -
GuyD;12

But if I update with a script (in post update request) the value of GuyD to 1000
Will the index be :

GuyA;150 -
GuyB;101 -
GuyE;90 -
GuyC;74 -
GuyD;1000

or

GuyD;1000 -
GuyA;150 -
GuyB;101 -
GuyE;90 -
GuyC;74

Please i'm talking specifically about a sorted index : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html
Can't seem to find the information anywhere.

Basicly : Are updates manage the same way as inserts in a sorted index ? I know i've got an advantage with an insert as it will be indexed in a sorted way, but do I keep it if an update changing the order is done afterwards ?

thx

ps : my mapping/settings : (I removed irrelevant parts)

```
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "sort.field": "Counter", 
      "sort.order": "desc",
......,
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "Type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "Counter":{
        "type":"integer"
      }.....
```

Comment: I think this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67945375/4604579 (hint: index sorting doesn't mean you don't have to specify a sort clause at search time. it would be ok if you force-merge your one-shard index to a single segment, but in any other cases you need to specify sorting at search time as well)

Comment: @Val Thx, i've edited the question to take in account your answer. I was kind of guessing it works like that. I'm mostly interested by the first part of my question.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, I still think that other thread answers your question. The problem is that your query has no sort clause, hence why your results are not sorted

Comment: [Index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-sorting-elasticsearch-6-0) is mainly a query optimization feature, i.e. it stores data in a way that makes queries more efficient, it doesn't mean that your data will always return in a sorted manner without having to specify it.

Comment: Ok i'll remove the second part of my question. It might be confusing. What I'm asking is : does an update act the same way as an insert in a sorted index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update is a GET + INSERT + DELETE, so yes, it behaves the same way. ES will mark the old document as deleted in its segment and the new document will be stored in a sorted way in the new segment.

Once segments are merged (eventually), it will make no difference whether you inserted the document only once or whether you inserted and updated it after the fact, the newly created segments will also be sorted the same way as the old ones.

So concretely, what is going to happen is this:

In the older segment A:

```
GuyA;150 - GuyB;101 - GuyE;90 - GuyC;74 - GuyD;12 
                                         [DELETED]
```

In the new segment B (say you also have a new GuyF and GuyG that were indexed before GuyD was updated):

```
GuyG;2500 - GuyD;1000 - GuyF;134
```

Both the old and new segments are sorted and once both get merged into a new segment C, that segment will look like this:

```
GuyG;2500 - GuyD;1000 - GuyA;150 - GuyF;134 - GuyB;101 - GuyE;90 - GuyC;74
```